# не могу получить ожидаемый ответ от QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Всем привет. Пытаюсь использовать классы `QNetworkAccessManager`, `QNetworkRequest`, `QNetworkReply`, чтобы скачать данные с сайта, но в выводе получаю то, что ниже. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как это исправить?

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
QNetworkReplyHttpImplPrivate::_q_startOperation was called more than once 
QUrl("https://auto.ru/tver/cars/all/?utm_source=yandex_direct&utm_medium=direct.brand&utm_campaign=460_han")
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
```

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/110861/qsslsocket-usage-throws-errors-cannot-resolve-crypto_num_locks-etc/6

Comment: openssl у меня установлен

Comment: Какая версия Qt и OpenSSL?

Comment: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)/
Qt 5.12

Comment: Но когда в терминале прописываю qmake -v то пишет что команда qmake не найдена

Comment: qmake из терминала и должен быть виден, если вы только не установили PATH. В ошибке написано qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL. То бишь, несовместимые версии. Посмотрите через MaintenanceTool   чтобы у вас для соответствующего Qt   был установлен соответствующий SSL

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144464/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-ahmed-08).

Comment: dll библиотеки openssl положите в каталог программы. Или хотябы сделайте их доступными через PATH